# Get values of other custom fields in field layout override

Tags: custom-field, com-content, joomla-3.9, repeatable-field, com-fields

1. I am using a repeatable custom field for articles in Joomla! 3.9.16 with an alternative layout (override) of `com_fields/layouts/field/render.php` and an override of `plugins/fields/repeatable/tmpl/repeatable.php` to show the fields content in columns "After Display". This is working fine.
2. The number of columns should depend on the value of a radio-field of the same field-group without "Automatic Display". I can not get this running.

The problem is that I do not get the value of this radio field into the field-layout. I think this is because I do not get the `item-id` of the current article via `$this->item` or `$displayData['item']`. It is no problem to get the 'number-of-columns' value in other overrides like the fields-layout `com_fields/layouts/fields/render.php` or the often used `blog_item.php` etc.,  but I want to do this just in the alternative layout if possible.

The following render.php is a simpler version of my code without stuff like links or images and without all the different versions I tried to get the field-value of `'number-of-columns'` to `$numberOfColumns`. Just kept the variable where it should be echoed.

I was looking into almost every question about "custom fields" on stackexchange and other sites. Did try the helpers and different answers to fetch the item-id and field-values but without any luck.

**render.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (!key_exists('field', $displayData))
{
    return;
}

$field = $displayData['field'];
$value = $field->value;


if ($value == '')
{
    return;
}

?>

<div class="cols-<?php echo $numberOfColumns; ?>">    
    <?php   
        $obj = json_decode($value, true);
        foreach ($obj as $value) : 

            $headline = $value['Headline'];
            $text= $value['Text'];
    ?>     
        <div class="item">
            <h3><?php echo $headline; ?></h3>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**repeatable.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$fieldValue = $field->value;

if ($fieldValue === '')
{
    return;
}

// Get the values
$fieldValues = json_decode($fieldValue, true);

if (empty($fieldValues))
{
    return;
}

echo $fieldValue;
```

Comment: Are these custom fields on a component you developed yourself or on one of the Joomla core components? (It's so that we can know what files are easily editable).

Comment: Just custom fields for articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an override of `com_fields/layouts/fields/render.php`. Find this line:

```
$content = FieldsHelper::render($context, 'field.' . $layout, array('field' => $field));
```

Change it to also pass the item to field layout:

```
$content = FieldsHelper::render($context, 'field.' . $layout, array('field' => $field, 'item' => $item));
```

The item with its fields is now accessible in `com_fields/layouts/field/render.php`.

Comment: Awesome thats exactly what i was looking for thank you so much!!!

Comment: Nice solution! Very neat :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a backstop solution, for using if no-one comes up with a better idea.

The basic approach is to use a plugin which is triggered by `onContentPrepare`. In this plugin it gets and processes the custom fields to find the `number-of-columns` field. It finds the value of this field and stores it in a PHP global variable, which then can be accessed in the render function.

I developed the plugin in a folder `plg_content_setcolumns`, and here are the files:

`setcolumns.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.8" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>Set number of columns</name>
    <description>Plugin to set number of columns from a custom field</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="setcolumns">setcolumns.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

`setcolumns.php`

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentSetColumns extends JPlugin
{
     public function onContentPrepare($context, $item, $params, $offset)
     {
         if ($context == "com_content.article") 
        {
            JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
            $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $item);
            global $ncols;
            $ncols = false;
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                if ($field->name == 'number-of-columns')
                {
                    $ncols = $field->value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then access $GLOBALS['ncols'] in your render code.

You may have to change some variables to suit your own field names.